# Reserved Error when capturing changes on Access 2013 Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the code within the following link within an Access 2013 form to capture changes made to records: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-simple-solution-for-tracking-changes-to-access-data/

I have the `ErrorHandler` commented out and am getting a `"<Reserved Error>"` within the line: `If (.Value <> .OldValue or ((Not IsNull ...`. This causes the statement not to read *True* and is skipped over.

I'm calling this `Sub` in BeforeUpdate trigger on the *Review Form*:

```
Sub ReviewFormAuditTrail(frm As Form, recordid As Control)
    'Track changes to data.
    'recordid identifies the pk field's corresponding
    'control in frm, in order to id record.
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim varBefore As Variant
    Dim varAfter As Variant
    Dim strControlName As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ChangeReason As Variant
    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'Get changed values.
      For Each ctl In frm.Controls
      With ctl
    'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
    If .ControlType = acComboBox Then
      'Changed this is allow for both null to value and value to null
       If (.Value <> .OldValue) Or ((Not IsNull(.OldValue) And IsNull(.Value))) Or ((IsNull(.OldValue) And Not IsNull(.Value))) Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        ChangeReason = Forms![Review Form]!ChangeReason
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "xAudit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue, ChangeReason) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & "," _
           & cDQ & ChangeReason & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      End If

    ElseIf .ControlType = acTextBox Then
      'Changed this is allow for both null to value and value to null
      If (.Value <> .OldValue) Or ((Not IsNull(.OldValue) And IsNull(.Value))) Or ((IsNull(.OldValue) And Not IsNull(.Value))) Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        ChangeReason = Forms![Review Form]!ChangeReason
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "xAudit (EditDate, User, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue, ChangeReason) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("username") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & "," _
           & cDQ & ChangeReason & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      End If
    End If
    End With
  Next
  Set ctl = Nothing
  Exit Sub

'Added to ignore the error produced from processing in joined tables
ErrHandler:
'If Err.Number = 3251 Then
'    Response = acDataErrContinue
'Else
'    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine _
'    & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, "Error"
'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'Reserved Error' on the .OldValue's within the If (.Value <> .OldValue or ((Not IsNull ... line.

Function is called using,

    Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Call ReviewFormAuditTrail(Me, Seq)
    End Sub

Comment: Have you tried compact and repair? You could simply have a corrupt file

Comment: I have, both front and back ends.

Comment: I'm now getting a Run-time error '0' Reserved Error.

Comment: Why are you commenting out error handler? What description does it relay? Also, where do you assign *cDQ* variable?

Comment: I'm commenting out the error handler to get the true error to research.  When doing so, I receive a Run-time error '0' Reserved Error. The 'cDQ' variable is assigned at the top of the module Const cDQ As String = """"

Comment: Quotes should only enclose strings, not dates or integers. Please see below parameterized query approach. Also, escape the reserved word `[User]` with square brackets. But issue may be the `.OldValue` call as control may not have such a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the industry standard when using SQL at application layer (i.e., VBA) by using a parameterized query with MS Access' [QueryDef.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao) which I assume is the crux of your issue.

With this approach you divorce SQL from VBA for better readability and maintainability without need to concatenate or enclose with quotes. Your above link runs a VBA concatenated SQL string and curiously does not combine the two repetitive `If` blocks:

**SQL** *(save as you would any MS Access query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS paramEditDate Date, paramUser Text(255), paramRecordID Long, 
           paramSourceTable Text(255), paramSourceField Text(255), 
           paramBeforeValue Text(255), paramAfterValue Text(255), paramChangeReason Text(255);
INSERT INTO xAudit (EditDate, [User], RecordID, SourceTable
                    SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue, ChangeReason)
VALUES (paramEditDate, paramUser, paramRecordID, paramSourceTable,
        paramSourceField, paramBeforeValue, paramAfterValue, paramChangeReason);
```

**VBA** *(pass form name as argument and use `Forms()` collection)*

```
Sub ReviewFormAuditTrail(frm_name As String, recordid As Control)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler    
    'Track changes to data.
    'recordid identifies the pk field's corresponding
    'control in frm, in order to id record.

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim varBefore As Variant, varAfter As Variant, ChangeReason As Variant
    Dim strControlName As String, strSQL As String
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    'Get changed values.
    For Each ctl In Forms(frm_name).Controls
       With ctl
          'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
          If .ControlType = acComboBox Or .ControlType = acTextBox Then
             'Changed this is allow for both null to value and value to null
              If (.Value <> .OldValue) Or ((Not IsNull(.OldValue) And IsNull(.Value))) _
                Or ((IsNull(.OldValue) And Not IsNull(.Value))) Then

                   varBefore = .OldValue
                   varAfter = .Value
                   strControlName = .Name
                   ChangeReason = Forms![Review Form]!ChangeReason

                   ' RETRIEVE SAVED QUERY
                   Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

                   ' BIND PARAMS
                   qdef!paramEditDate = Now()
                   qdef!paramUser = Environ("username")
                   qdef!paramRecordID = recordid.Value
                   qdef!paramSourceTable = Forms(frm_name).RecordSource
                   qdef!paramSourceField = strControlName
                   qdef!paramBeforeValue = varBefore
                   qdef!paramAfterValue = varAfter
                   qdef!paramChangeReason = ChangeReason

                   ' EXECUTE QUERY
                   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

              End If
          End if
       End With
    Next ctl

ExitHandler:
   Set ctl = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
   Exit Sub 

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, "Runtime Error"
  Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: This is definitely a more compact version of the function with the external query.  Thank you.  I'm still getting the Run-Time Error '0' though.  When stepping through the function and hovering over Dim varBefore as Variant, Dim varAfter as Varient, Dim ChangeReason as Variant etc. I see '=Empty.'  Does this mean I am calling the Function incorrectly using Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Call ReviewFormAuditTrail(Me, Id) ?
End Sub

Comment: Errors are never zero. First, are you compiling your code to check syntax (VBA IDE: `Debug / Compile`)?  Second, are you using exactly the error handler (with exit handler) I propose? Finally, there may be something about your combobox and textbox controls. Can users actually enter/change values? Are you using a bound or unbound form?

Comment: I do always compile before running and am using the Error / Exit handler exactly as you provided.  Users are able to edit appropriate fields (Enabled = Yes in Properties).  All fields are bound except for ChangeReason,  However I doubt this field is causing the error as the error is produced before getting to lines relevant to ChangeReason.

Comment: Does this code reside in a standard module? If so `Me.` is not available. Try passing the name of form as string argument and then use `Forms` collection. See edit, no longer using `frm` object.

Comment: The code is residing in a standard module.  I received a type mismatch error (BeforeUpdate line in yellow) with this attempt using the below to call the function.

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Call ReviewFormAuditTrail(Me, RecordID)
End Sub

Comment: You have to pass form name in caller which would be a string type: `Call ReviewFormAuditTrail(Me.Form.Name, RecordID)`.

Comment: Somehow I am still getting "Run-time error '0' Reserved Error."

Comment: Remove the inner `If` and its `End If` but keep its code. If no error, add the `If` back and test each of the 3 `Or` conditions by themselves then together to isolate issue. It might be `OldValue`.

Comment: Another debugging test, just after first `If` block but before second, add line `Debug.Print .Name` which prints. to immediate window (Ctrl+G) in VBA IDE. This can show which control is erring out.

Comment: Resolved:  As suggested, adding 'Debug.Print .Name' showed the name of a textbox with a calculation in it's Control Source.  This text box and it's calculation was not needed and thus the calculation was never updated and it's error message was ignored during the development of the form.  However, since the textbox is a .control in the form, the code was going to loop through it, and with an error as it's value the code was doomed to 'error out' from the get go.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, your expertise is very much appreciated.  You have provided me great insight to .QueryDefs and provided a cleaner version of the function.  Thank you again!

Comment: Excellent to hear. Glad it worked out. Happy coding into the new year!